# Changing Text Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, textfield

I am writing a HTML page and some JavaScript to go with it.

the scenario is I have a div with `id = "textField"`

inside this div I just want to display 2 texts that change every 2 second.

heres my js code:

```
var textArray = [text, text2];

var textIndex= 0;

var para = document.createElement("p");

var text = document.createTextNode("Floating Text");

var text2 = document.createTextNode("Another Text");


var textField = document.getElementById("textField");


function changeText(){

textField.setAttribute("p", textArray[textIndex]);

para.appendChild(textArray[textIndex]);

textField.appendChild(para);

textIndex++;

if(textIndex >= textArray.length){

textIndex = 0;
}

}

setInterval(changeText, 2000);
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with your html too please : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var textArray = ["Floating Text", "Another Text"];
var textIndex= 0;

var textField = document.getElementById("textField");

function changeText()
{
    textField.innerHTML =textArray[textIndex];
    textIndex++;

    if(textIndex >= textArray.length) textIndex = 0;        
}

setInterval(changeText, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reassign the innerhtml of the div.

Create your phrases manually like so:

```
var str1 = "<p>Text 1</p>";
var str2 = "<p>Text 2</p>";
var textField = document.getElementById('id');

function changeText( str1, str2 ){
    textField.innerHTML = str1 + "<br />\n" + str2;
}
```

You don't need to add and remove elements dynamically for what it looks like youre doing, you only need to change the innerHTML if you are only showing messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type=text/javascript>

function changeText(textA, textB){
    var textAModificar= document.getElementById('textField');
    textAmodificar.value = textA + textB;
}

var myVar = setInterval(changeText(Chuck, Norris),2000) 

To finalize interval -->clearInterval(myVar);
</script>
```